# How can we put a variant message ( one of a few message types ) inside a protobuf message?

Tags: protocol-buffers

How can we put a variant message ( one of a few message types ) inside a protobuf message?

```
message typeA {
    ....
}

message typeB {
    ....
}

message typeC {
    [typeB|typeA] payload;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
message TypeC {
  optional TypeA a = 1;
  optional TypeB b = 2;
}
```

If there are a lot of variants, you might also want to add a tag field so that you don't have to check `has_*()` for each one.

This is covered in the Protobuf docs:  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#union

PS. This missing feature of Protobufs is fixed in [Cap'n Proto](http://capnproto.org), a new serialization system by the same author (me):  Cap'n Proto implements ["unions"](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/language.html#unions) for this purpose.  I had also implemented unions in Protobufs before leaving Google, but didn't manage to get my change merged into mainline before I left.  Sorry.  :(

EDIT: It looks like the Protobuf team eventually merged my change and released version 2.6.0 with it. :) See [the `oneof` declaration](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof).

Comment: Thanks for creating `oneof`, you rock!

Answer (score 33):

Check out the new `oneof` feature in version 2.6: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#oneof

You can now do something like this:

```
message TypeC {
    oneof oneof_name {
        TypeA a = 1;
        TypeB b = 2;
    }
}
```

Fields in the same `oneof` will share memory and only one field can be set at the same time.

Comment: How to check which one is set? I have int, string ,boolean, etc. So how to determine which one is filled?

Comment: currently I'm using the test below, but protobuffer probably has something more elegant:

`!Proto.GetData.getDefaultInstance().equals(all.getGetData());`

Comment: another way is to do a switch on the string value which is present when you do `all.getMessageCase()`

Comment: Will this still work if TypeA and/or TypeB have a repeatable member?

Comment: @ChrisMcCowan unfortunately, oneof's don't allow repeated fields