# Google-protobuf: How to create unions using Google protocol buffer

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

I am currently trying to use Google Protocol Buffers for C language.
I am a little unsure as to how to create a C union using GPB.

For example, with a proto file as follows:

```
message msgToSend
{
 required Type msg_type=1; //Type is a predefined enum to determine message type
 optional ReqMsg1 msg1=2;
 optional ReqMsg2 msg2=3;
}
```

I expect above to generate a `union` upon compilation but a structure is generated as follows:

```
struct _msgToSend
{
 ProtobufCMessage base;
 Type msg_type;
 ReqMsg1 msg1;
 ReqMsg2 msg2;
}
```

Comment: Please consider accepting [this answer that mentions `oneof`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40040658/28169). I can't delete my accepted answer.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

I don't think you can.

In Protobuf "optional" doesn't mean "it's either this or this other" like with C unions; it means "this might be here". That's why you're getting a C structure that can express both optional fields being present.

At work this alone was enough to make me implement a Protobuf replacement system, since we really wanted unions.

Comment: right! since eventually just the filled data gets packed

Comment: Maybe check https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof for unions

Comment: @Quarra Ooh, I didn't know about that one. Is it (very) new? Tried to figure that out but failed (I don't follow Protobuf).

Comment: @unwind I'm using protobuf 2.6.1 at the moment in my project and oneofs are already there. 2.6.1 was released on 21st of Oct 2014 AFAIK. Oneofs are in Language Guide for proto2, so I assume that oneofs were there from version 2.0.0.

Comment: According to this answer oneof was released with 2.6.0, which came out 2014-08-15 http://stackoverflow.com/a/20985344/306

Answer (score 49):

In protobuf there is a dedicated structure for that (I'm using it in C++ though, not sure if it will work in pure C):

```
message MyUnion {
    oneof MyUnionOneof {
        bool booleanValue = 1;
        string stringValue = 2;
    }
}
```

Check out this link: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof