# Serialization of boost::variant using protobuf

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, protocol-buffers, variant

I have to serialize `std::queue` that contains `boost::variant`.  Variant has about 20 different structures. 
What is better/prefered way of representing variant in proto3? I mean, should I use `oneof` or `any`?
How about their performance?

I do not ask how to do that I do not know what is the best solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we put a variant message ( one of a few message types ) inside a protobuf message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970836/how-can-we-put-a-variant-message-one-of-a-few-message-types-inside-a-protobu)

Answer (score 1):

You start the other way round. You write a .proto file that defines (in Google's protobuf schema language) the "messages" you wish to define. One of these can be a 'oneof' containing lots of others. You then compile that .proto file using the Protocol Buffers compiler, and you end up with C++ source code that implements those messages as C++ classes derived from a library of base classes. These classes have serialisation routines built in. At no point do you use Boost or hand written C++ classes.

Boost::variant might very well be the equivalent of protobuf's 'oneof', but you'd not use it to contain different protobuf messages, because that's what 'oneof' does for you. Mixing Boost::variant with GPB's own style of doing things is likely asking for confusing code.