# C++ implementation of protobuf `oneof` feature for non-protobuf class

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

The protobuf `oneof` feature is great. But it only can be used when the fields in `oneof` are either a primitive type or a protobuf message. What if I have two classes `A` and `B`, which are defined by C++ code instead of protobuf messages, and I want to implement a class `AorB` which is like:

```
message AorB {
    oneof oneof_name {
        A a = 1;
        B b = 2;
    }
}
```

I tried to read the generated C++ code of a `oneof` field to see how that is implemented. But it's pretty complicated. Is there any concise way to implement this? Or any template which I can use directly?

Comment: I don't know protobufs, but it sounds like [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: [In fact, `oneof` was created to answer the same question in reverse!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20985344/1171191)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of C++ you're able to use, your options are `std::variant`, roll your own with variadic templates, or roll your own with `union`. `std::variant` was added to the language in C++17 and will definitely be the easiest to manage. The variadic template version is tricky.

`union` works to the beginning of the language and would look something like.

```
struct MyAorB {
  union {
    A a;
    B b;
  };
  ~MyAorB() { destruct(); }
  MyAorB& operator=(const MyAorB&) = delete;
  MyAorB& operator=(MyAorB&&) = delete;
  MyAorB(const MyAorB&) = delete;
  MyAorB(const MyAorB&&) = delete;
  enum { HOLDS_NONE, HOLDS_A, HOLDS_B } which_one = HOLDS_NONE;
  A& get_A() { assert(which_one == HOLDS_A); return a; }
  B& get_B() { assert(which_one == HOLDS_B); return b; }
  void set_A(A new_a) { which_one = HOLDS_A; destruct(); a = std::move(new_a); }
  void set_B(B new_b) { which_one = HOLDS_B; destruct(); b = std::move(new_b); }
  void destruct() {
    switch (which_one) {
      case HOLDS_A: a.~A(); break;
      case HOLDS_B: b.~B(); break;
      default: break;
    }
  }
};
```

at a baseline that kinda maybe works. There's a pile of details to get it right, though. The basics of it are that a union puts the values in overlapping memory, only one is valid at a time, and it's undefined behavior to access the wrong one. You also need to manually destruct before re-assigning the held value.

I probably missed a detail somewhere in there. I'd rather leave it to `std::variant` but if you need to write your own discriminated union, it would start something like the code above.

More details on variant here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant